# Find regular expression of the following language

Tags: regex

A regular expression for the language of all strings over {a,b} alphabet that does not start with `aaa`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. It's very unclear what you want to achive, what your problems are and what you've tried to solve them.

Comment: My answer was not correct. Let me see if I can come up with something else.

Comment: If you have a solution, please, by all means. [edit] the question. As it currently stands, your question is off-topic. Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. The most important thing you'll learn there is **show your effort**, thus please, do [edit] the question with your current attempt, which will constitute a [mcve].

Comment: ok i will show my effort wait a sec please.

Comment: You should go to class and learn the material rather than skipping and asking your homework questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the DFA for your language:

[image]

and this is the regular expression you are looking for:

```
(b + ab + aab) (a + b)*
```

---

If you want a regular expression for a language that does not **contain** `aaa`:

[image]

```
(b + ab + aab)* (a + aa)?
```

Interestingly enough, after I Googled your question to see whether my solution is correct, I saw [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1933982) that is almost the same as mine. Refer to it for more explanation.